# Can't Specialize Function Call in C++ Template Specialization with Math

Tags: c++

I'm running across an interesting problem where I'm specializing a parent class with some math, but then getting a compiler error (GCC 11.2.0, tried C++17/20/23) when I try to specialize any function used inside the child class:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t N>
class Test
{
    public:
        template <typename T>
        void Foo(void)
        {
        }
        
        void Bar(void)
        {
            std::cout << "N is " << N << "\n";
        }
};

template <std::size_t N>
class Tester: public Test<5 + (N * 2)>
{
    public:
        void Baz(void)
        {
            // Causes an error:
            //
            //      main.cpp: In member function 'void Tester<N>::Baz()':
            //      main.cpp:33:30: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
            //         33 |             this->Foo<uint8_t>();
            //            |                              ^
            //      main.cpp:33:32: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
            //         33 |             this->Foo<uint8_t>();
            //            |                                ^
            //this->Foo<uint8_t>();
            
            // Works fine
            this->Bar();
        }
};

int main()
{
    Tester<1> test;
    test.Baz();
}
```

If I comment out the `Foo<uint8_t>()` operation, it compiles and prints out `7`, as expected.

If I replace the `5 + (N * 2)` with a non-math expression (e.g. `5`) it compiles just fine with the `Foo<uint8_t>()` operation uncommented, and it prints out `5`.

Is this a known limitation or bug? Am I just doing something weird that isn't allowed? Seems like it should be fine, given it works with the math if I comment that call out.

Comment: GCC gives me a relevant warning: *"warning: expected 'template' keyword before dependent template name [-Wmissing-template-keyword]"* - and adding that as `this->template Foo<uint8_t>();` does indeed fix the error

Comment: This seems to be compiled just fine for me, I'm using VS2022 which use cl compiler

Comment: @UnholySheep make that an answer

Comment: "_when I try to specialize any function used inside the child class_": You are not specializing any function or class anywhere by the way.

Comment: @thedemons It is incorrect of MSVC to accept it without the `template` keyword.

Comment: @user17732522 Ahh sorry, you're right, I'm using that too broadly.